# How can we download pictures of properties using librets c#?

Tags: c#, rets

I have tried code from here https://www.reso.org/c-sharp-photo-download-example/ but it's not working and show picture size 1KB.

Below Code I tried

```
 using (librets.GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest("Property", "Photo"))
                {
                    request.AddAllObjects(CurrentMLS);


                    GetObjectResponse response = session.GetObject(request);

                    foreach (ObjectDescriptor objectDescriptor in response)
                    {
                        string objectKey = objectDescriptor.GetObjectKey();
                        int objectId = objectDescriptor.GetObjectId();
                        string contentType = objectDescriptor.GetContentType();
                        string description = objectDescriptor.GetDescription();

                        Console.Write(objectKey + " object #" + objectId);
                        if (description.Length != 0)
                            Console.Write(", desription: " + description);
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        string outputFileName = photoFilePath+"\\"+objectKey + "-" + objectId + ".jpg";

                        Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFileName);
                       
                            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
                            Stream stream = objectDescriptor.GetDataStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                            int bytesRead;
                            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                            {
                                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                       
                        outputStream.Close();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: The close reason message links are confusing. What I mean with my close vote is [mcve] and explanation of what happens and what you expect to happens.

Comment: Open the generated file in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're filtering by contentType.  If you trust the RETS server to send properly formatted content type strings, then you could filter the objects down to JPEGs only using something like this:

```
            string contentType = objectDescriptor.GetContentType();

            // skip objects that don't appear to be JPEGs
            if (contentType != "image/jpeg") { continue; };
```